# Retrieve WTL object from handle

Tags: c++, casting, atl, wtl

I had to rewrite a custom file dialog (derived from MFC's CFileDialog) to WTL's CFileDialog. I have a bit of a problem to retrieve data when I don't have access to the dialog object itself. Imagine the following.

I have a member in the class

```
static WNDPROC m_wndProc;
```

I initialize it in the following static member fnct.

```
void CMyFileDialog::OnInitDone(LPOFNOTIFY lpon)
{
  m_wndProc = (WNDPROC)::SetWindowLong(thisHWND, GWL_WNDPROC, reinterpret_cast<long>
                                       (&CMyFileDialog::WndProcSelect));
}
```

The handle comes into the callback method with no problem and I can "connect" to it with CWindow

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CMyFileDialog::WndProcSelect(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  // ...
  CWindow callerWnd(hwnd);
}
```

And here, I don't know the real methodology to convert the CWindow to my CMyFileDialog. As I think, this CWindow class is just connected somehow to the handle itself, but does not the same object as it was created before. So for example, if I have a CString or other members in my CMyFileDialog, it won't access its state, because it was created in another object.

Comment: Why are you changing the WNDPROC? Can't you simply use the `BEGIN_MSG_MAP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use `SetWindowLongPtr` with your "this" pointer, then it would be fairly easy to extract the pointer to your CMyFileDialog.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I see I had it wrong with changing the window proc, so I will try that first.

Comment: I think this answer will be my choice. I forgot the reason why I used this wndproc override... I had to override the Selection button's functionality in that dialog which is hidden by default.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing something wrong here. You have access to the message map without having to modify the WndProc (that is something that the `CFileDialogImpl` will have already done).

See for example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12999/WTL-for-MFC-Programmers-Part-IX-GDI-Classes-Common#usingcfiledialog, where they simply

```
BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMyFileDialog)
   CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CFileDialogImpl<CMyFileDialog>)
END_MSG_MAP()
```